# What is the meaning of 制限 when talking about phones/phone numbers?

Tags: meaning, words

I have my phone set to Japanese, and I got a call from " 制限 ". I understand that 制限 means "restricted", but in this context does it mean a blocked number, or something else?

Comment: Isn't this more of a technology question than a Japanese question?  Like, if you don't understand what "restricted" really entails in English either, then it's more about who/what restricted the number...which is a matter of technology.  My $0.02.

Comment: did the call go through?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a 100% confirmation so far but I strongly suspect it means “caller ID blocked”.